# How to call a Header (an ERB) in my application body index ? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, erb

im trying to make a web page in Ruby on Rails but im having some problem trying to split my page into various ERB files to split my page in: head,foot and body, now my question is how can i call each one of my views, in my body page to build the entire web page. thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: Did you read the RailsGuides about Structuring Layouts (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a `_header.html.erb`, you call it inside you `application.html.erb` by typing `'render 'header'` (without the underscore) in your `body` tag